# What are the characteristics that we can use to identify polynomials that have singular points?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, singular-values

A typical example of polynomials that have singular points is $y^2 - x^2 - x^3 = 0$, where point $(0,0)$ is the singular point.
However, the situation is changed if a linear term is added to this polynomial.
Say $y^2 - x^2 - x^3 - x = 0\ $ or $\ y^2 - x^2 - x^3 - t = 0$.

It seems like given a polynomial $f$, the (affine or projective) variety of it, i.e., $V(f)$ won't be singular if $f$ has at least one linear term.
I can see why $\ f(x,y,t) = y^2 - x^2 - x^3 - t$ is non-singular, because the partial derivative of $\ f$ with respect to $\ t$ can never be $0$.

But I am wondering how to generalize this to all polynomials in $\ K[x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n]$? Or is there any material that discusses the patterns on polynomials such that the varieties of them will/won't have singular points?

I know that the Jacobian criteria can do this by checking one point after another. But there could be infinitely many of points to be checked. So I am thinking if there is any such pattern on the polynomials that we can determine the singular points at a high level, or even just for special classes of polynomials.

Moreover, what kind of patterns/characteristics of the polynomial can help determine the dimension of set of singular points?

Please someone guide me to some sources related to this.
Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are asking : you seem to want some criterion but something different from the Jacobian criteria ? This is what is used in practice... Be careful with the sentence "$V(f)$ won't be singular if $f$ has at least one linear term", the correct version is "$V(f)$ won't be singular at $(0,0)$ if $V(f)$ has at least one linear term", you still need to check every other points.

Comment: Hi, Roland. I am looking for sth that can describe multiple singular points at the same time. For example, given a polynomial $f$, can I efficiently determine that the singular points of of $V(f)$ is multiple lines if it is indeed such case, just by looking at some (unknown) patterns/characteristics of $f$ itself?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, the standard way to solve problems like this is to use the Jacobian criteria and then check whether any of the places the Jacobian is not full rank actually lie on the variety. Since both these steps are relatively computationally efficient (calculating derivatives, determinants, and intersections of varieties are all things we know how to do algorithmicly), this should be a starting point. Have you tried this and had it perform less well than you want?